# How does DispatchQueue.main.async store it's blocks

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

I have a code similar to this:

```
func fetchBalances() -> Observable<Result<[User], Error>> {

    Observable.create { observer in
        
        var dataChangeDisposable: Disposable?
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let realm = try! Realm()
            let user = realm.objects(UserData.self)
            dataChangeDisposable = Observable.collection(from: user)
                .map { $0.map { UserData.convert($0) } }
                .subscribe(onNext: {
                    observer.onNext(.success($0))
                })
        }

        return Disposables.create {
            dataChangeDisposable?.dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use some thread with run loop in order to maintain subscription to Realm database (Realm's restriction). For now I'm using DispatchQueue.main.async {} method and I noticed that subscription remains active all the time, how does DispatchQueue.main stores it's submitted blocks and if Observable destroys does it mean that I'm leaking blocks in memory?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here as that code circumvents Realm and may really cause a lot of other issues; Realm objects are now disconnected from Realm, they are no longer lazily loaded, that `user` is a Results and will contain multiple users, not just one, and that code will likely cause object threading issues. Take a moment and read through the Realm Documentation on [Realm Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications). Also what does *maintain subscription* mean in this use case. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay I mean that while I keep a subscription alive I'm still getting updates from Realm, thus I made a conclusion that DispatchQueue.main keeps my block alive and stores it somewhere internally, and the question was am I going to have leaked blocks in memory because of DispatchQueue.main?

Comment: The accepted answer specifically addresses disposing of the Dispatch queue and that's not really the issue with your code. You should not be creating a 'subscription' to the Realm database like that and you *really* don't want to process Realm results through Swift constructs - that's going to be disastrous for larger datasets and very inefficient. Read through the link to see how to properly work with realm notifications, noting this **Notifications are always delivered on the thread that they were originally registered on. That thread must have a currently running run loop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block sent to the dispatch queue is deleted immediately after execution. It isn't stored for very long at all.

If your subscription "remains active all the time" then it's because it's not being disposed of properly. Likely what is happening here is that the block sent to `Disposables.create` is being called before `dataChangeDisposable` contains a value.

Test my hypothesis by changing the code to:

```
return Disposables.create {
    dataChangeDisposable!.dispose()
}
```

If your app crashes because `dataChangeDisposable` is nil, then that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a bug in my code, I thought that Realm needs Run Loop for delivering notifications all the time, but if dispatch queue deletes block immediately after execution how "leaked" subscription gets notifications from Realm?

Comment: I don't know anything about how to use Realm. I'm just answering the question about why your subscription does dispose properly. I suggest you create a new question about how to get notifications from Realm (or search for that question, because it has likely already been answered.)